# Connect and query database in Managed C++ using SqlConnection

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio-2012, sqlconnection

I'm building a project in C++ in Visual Studio 2012 and I've started by writing some classes for database access. Using [SQL Server data tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) I've managed to create a SQL project in my solution.

Now, my question is: How can I use the types in System::Data::SqlClient namespace to connect to the database in my code? All the examples I get are using the database as reference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my answer helps someone, I have used the classes SqlDataReader and SqlCommand in order to select some data from db. Note that I'm fetching the ConnectionString from an App.Config I've created earlier ([how it could be done](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21036/Working-with-Configuration-Files-app-config-in-C-C)).

```
SqlDataReader getSqlDataReader(String ^_sql)
{
    SqlDataReader ^_sqlDataReader = nullptr;

    SqlConnection ^_connection = gcnew SqlConnection();

    ConnectionStringSettings ^connectionSettings = ConfigurationManager::ConnectionStrings["AppDefaultConnection"];
    this->_connection->ConnectionString = connectionSettings->ConnectionString;

    try {
        this->_connection->Open();
    } 

    catch (Exception ^_exception)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Error : "  + _exception->Message);
        return nullptr;
    }

    try
    {
        SqlCommand ^_sqlCommand = gcnew SqlCommand(_sql,_connection);
        _sqlDataReader = _sqlCommand->ExecuteReader();
    }

    catch(Exception ^_exception)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Error : "  + _exception->Message);
        return nullptr;
    }

    return _sqlDataReader;
}
```

To proper build the SQL we should be aware of the class SqlParameter ([example for C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)) and avoid SQL injection attacks.

To use the getSqlDataReader function:

```
   SqlDataReader ^reader = getSqlDataReader(yourParameterizedQueryString);

        List<TypeToFetch>^ data = gcnew List<TypeToFetch^>();
        if(reader != nullptr && reader->HasRows)
        {
            TypeToFetch^ typeToFetch = gcnew TypeToFetch();
            while(reader->Read())
            {
                    // example
                TypeToFetch->id = (int) reader["Id"];
                TypeToFetch->name = reader["Name"]->ToString();
                data->Add(typeToFetch);
            }
        }
```

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931747/insert-values-into-sql-server-table-using-sqldatareader) can help on INSERT.